# Stabilize a video using only one tracking piont

Tags: tracking

I have a video that I want to stabilize, tho the video itself is very stable the subject is moving. I want to keep the subject in the centre. and there is only one tracking point that is visible in every frame, Blender asks for 8 tracking points.

Answer (score 3):

Use Tripod tracking instead and this will solve without 3D reconstruction. Also send the tracker to 2D Stabilization, it is located in the Movie Clip editor's Properties panel (n-key). Now you will have a motion vector based on a single tracker.